# Select 2 elements with linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq

I need to select 2 cities in a table with linq:

**SOLUTION 1: just one query**

```
            var CityQuery = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CityId == City1Id || c.CityId == City2Id).Take(2)
                foreach (var item in CityQuery)
            {
                if (item.CityId == City1Id)
                { 
                    City1Name = item.CityName;
                }
                else
                {
                    City2Name = item.CityName;
                }
            }
```

or

**SOLUTION 2: execute 2 queries**

```
            var City1Query = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CityId == City1Id).FirsOrDefault();
            City1Name = City1Query.CityName;
            var City2Query = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CityId == City2Id).FirsOrDefault();
            City2Name = City2Query.CityName;
```

Which query is the most efficient ? What is the best practice ?

Comment: If you want the fastest one, you could use a StopWatch to check the execution time :)

Comment: The second one requires 2 round-trips to the database which, almost certainly, will be slower than the first one. However, there are a lot of factors in play here (indices v.s. full table scans etc.) so the only way to be sure is to measure. Also; this may vary a lot on a case-by-case basis for another bunch of factors.

Comment: Does the first 1 will "scan" all the database to try to found all possible results ?

Comment: better than StopWatch, you can use BenchmarkDotnet: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet. And I think the same that  RobIII.

Comment: Weird how "FirstOrDefault" is shaded blue when it's missing a "t"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, your Solution 1 should be faster since it makes a single round-trip to the database. However, whether that difference is significant or not depends on your use case.

Here's an alternative solution that only brings back the city names from the database (vs bringing back all columns). At first look, this might look like an inefficient cartesian product but the db engine will most likely optimize this, especially if there exist an index on the `CityId` column.

```
var result = from city1 in CityQuery where city1.CityId == City1Id
             from city2 in CityQuery where city2.CityId == City2Id
             select new 
             {
                 City1Name = c1.CityName, 
                 City2Name = c2.CityName
             };

City1Name = result.City1Name;
City2Name = result.City2Name;
```

Comment: I have just done the StopWatch test on my database, SOLUTION 1 is faster on my environment. Thank you !